# How to stop iPhone 6 lock screen from rotating to landscape mode

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an iPhone 6, running iOS 11. Before iOS 11, the lock screen would never rotate to landscape mode (similar to home screen, that never rotates). Since iOS 11 my lock screen has started rotating to landscape mode. I don't want this behaviour.

Can I stop my lock screen from rotating to landscape mode while letting the other apps auto rotate to landscape mode normally?

**UPDATE**

I have exact steps to reproduce:

1. Unlock phone
2. Open an app that supports landscape mode
3. Rotate the phone to landscape
4. Lock the phone while it is in landscape mode

Now the lock screen is in landscape and it is "locked" in landscape until I unlock the phone.

Comment: I wonder how you made the lock screen rotate in the first place.

Comment: Rotation is always unlocked on my phone. I upgraded to iOS 11 and the lock screen started rotating.

Comment: The lock screen? Where you enter your PIN or use Touch ID? Never got that to rotate...

Comment: Is this the Notification Center pulldown? Because that rotates on mine, but the lock screen does not.

Comment: Tried with Notes on a 7 plus, can’t reproduce the effect. Is this a specific app or does it happen with all?

Comment: @patrix all apps. Rotate the phone to landscape and press the power button.

Comment: Hmm https://www.dropbox.com/s/3r6cdx2n5d2hnp3/IMG_1323.TRIM.MOV?dl=0

Answer (score 3):

There is no separate setting that will stop only the lock screen from rotating to landscape while allowing the apps to change orientation.

Comment: Can you back up what you're saying? Any source or reference?

Comment: I don't have any source or reference. The answer is based on observation and experience using iOS.